# importing project from github to android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on android project using android studio 1.0.2, due to some issues I had to delete my local git repository. Now I am importing project from my remote git repository not directly into studio but only after cloning and then importing. (I have also tried to clone from android studio directly as well)

When I import it and I correct the path in /.idea/module.xml. Then it throws this error

```
13:04 PM Throwable: Assertion failed: Write access is allowed inside write-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runWriteAction())
```

I have tried almost everything I can such as remove .idea folder, remove *.iml file, doing invalidate caches and restart etc

But nothings work even after install fresh copy of Android studio and everything.

It seems like it is bug in android studio but still i have to import the project or some work around to continue working on it.
Any help would really [appreciated...already spent 1 day on it ...

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Is the code in the repository not set up for Android Studio?  Just trying to figure out what sort of importing you're doing.

Comment: unfortunetly not, yes I am trying everything ...did not get any clue yet..